# R Console thought the command hasn't finished yet and go to + mode

Tags: r

When I enter this code in R it works fine
[R works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUEOo.png)

```
r <- c(0.33732951,0.43556465,0.30636046,0.62461099,0.50852866,0.50000000,0.58672964,0.29569920,0.44354880,0.10928014,0.39103592,0.15000000,0.20277678,0.05547002,0.34786088,0.59259372,0.22456183,0.52085869,0.13411332,0.14000000,0.73546313,0.70886082,0.60574358,0.51000000,0.74603590,0.63419784,0.56821964,0.50000000,0.30750708,0.25300000,0.57458777,0.43225991,0.36255808,0.31200000,0.36088987,0.23500000,0.67900000,0.52780663,0.84877634,0.60100000,0.52312114,0.88016779,0.54786992,0.44100000,0.71454795,0.40600000,0.63336988,0.48430697,0.62300000,0.85775039,0.49700000,0.86755325,0.28000000,0.41000000,0.29000000,0.49000000,0.47584950,0.54614545,0.38933141,0.42177569,0.44000000,0.38000000,0.30000000,0.35000000,0.43782491,0.59376254,0.40183930,0.47980812,0.64908555,0.70267977,0.51212255,0.36324971,0.37531746,0.40356716,0.47217357,0.63844986,0.30000000,0.24000000,0.33000000,0.53979562,0.41000000,0.20000000,0.35000000,0.62699337,0.54691447,0.93206856,0.46946850,0.65527331,0.53214520,0.87832701,0.41905965,0.63000000,0.38354612,0.56000000,0.35676991,0.29922638,0.26470026,0.18989366,0.73214090,0.74000000,0.79819873,0.74000000,0.68839278,0.75000000,0.68839278,0.68000000,0.30000000,0.12000000,0.45000000,0.06000000,0.32000000,0.44165042,0.49694187,0.63526724,0.53084984,0.45700000,0.28336175,0.24317002,0.28464587,0.16522301,0.41483438,0.62062299,0.24000000,0.32346029,0.15000000,0.62325274,0.24000000,0.41000000,0.23000000,0.32165450,0.30173569,0.03187675,-0.04782179,0.02956562,0.07973255,-0.22000000,-0.02696799,0.50000000,0.29494534,0.43000000,0.24679100,0.57558910,0.24645372,0.50000000,0.30096463,0.63082172,0.38295544,0.27817034,0.40538389,0.17616607,0.45000000,0.11803126,0.44000000,0.20000000,0.70900000,0.31000000,0.78000000,0.24900000,0.40600000,0.36000000,0.41900000,0.64812911,0.28077588,0.63883770,0.21744889,0.13203260,0.05807479,0.34675230,0.13066828,0.17070882,0.07549723,0.39777792,0.65397387,0.64048987,0.51913389,0.56000000,0.31000000,0.42000000,0.69214473,0.46503474,0.56777497,0.27300000,0.32500000,0.33400000,0.34400000,0.36447006,0.32547228,0.22000000,0.22000000,0.25000000,0.36074535,0.35000000,0.28000000,0.05000000,0.49300000,0.43500000,0.48750000,0.30000000,0.63750000,0.41000000,0.83236786,0.69647321,0.59323981,0.62000000,0.69000000,0.42600000,0.56100000,0.59600000,0.63761434,0.36827862,0.61000000,0.34526120,0.43000000,0.34074078,0.50395263,0.39705038,0.33000000,0.62919823,0.62000000,0.49965742,0.50000000,0.64770406,0.61000000,0.81511084,0.73821398,0.62482030,0.67288340,0.59189332,0.85976843,0.36461257,0.83993087,0.59600000,0.67200000,0.65700000,0.67500000,0.34870942,0.63444530,0.81000000,0.41428134,0.45614037,0.41797478,0.20000000,0.26000000,0.36000000,0.45000000,0E-8,0.01000000,0.20000000,0.23000000,0.38000000,0.47968275,0.72166665,0.50000000,0.12700000,0.38651119,0.68878395,0.71000000,0.42000000,0.70000000,0.39000000,0.44988642,0.42124197,0.34000000,0.11000000,0.42000000,0.37000000,0.74541280,0.61012712,0.50246344,0.57498891,0.45985678,0.54804849,0.58633763,0.36000000,0.55715993,0.63899544,0.72252703,0.75500000,0.78300000,0.80000000,0.51094514,0.51211435,0.30000000,0.29000000,-0.09000000,0.29200000,0.48527820,0.36800000,0.48100000,0.12555004,0.40900000,0.56200000,0.23400000,0.56300000,0.38000000,0.49100000,0.52327502,0.53200000,0.45552468,0.04390000,0.49628505,0.52600000,0.50675055,0.45000000,0.30000000,0.56000000,0.53000000,0.38000000,0.55000000,0.49400000,0.41300000,0.50100000,0.73800000,0.48615496,0.59296173,0.62349262,0.39200000,0.43689994,0.64200000,0.64601018,0.72488244,0.63960215,0.63960215,0.48739278,0.18000000,0.56000000,0.60000000,0.50500939,0.34000000,0.50000000,0.61000000,0.53033987,0.36425313,0.48600000,0.66400000,0.42800000,0.52248837,0.55429714,0.38759566,0.61466918,0.06676300,0.08029551,0.07456011,0.07456011,0.05173567,0.05000000,0E-8,0.09000000,0.76800000,0.45900000,0.84700000,0.65100000,0.79754237,0.58286220,0.31153461,0.21323135,0.51900000,0.38700000,0.75400000,0.60600000,0.73178375,0.63758279,0.62884328,0.61547860,0.63892541,0.14773733,0.34210000,0.23908753,-0.07010000,0.76740585,0.48100000,0.64600000);
```

but in when I just add more values to combine it doesn't work.
[Going to finish the command mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bE9TN.png)

```
r <- c(0.33732951,0.43556465,0.30636046,0.62461099,0.50852866,0.50000000,0.58672964,0.29569920,0.44354880,0.10928014,0.39103592,0.15000000,0.20277678,0.05547002,0.34786088,0.59259372,0.22456183,0.52085869,0.13411332,0.14000000,0.73546313,0.70886082,0.60574358,0.51000000,0.74603590,0.63419784,0.56821964,0.50000000,0.30750708,0.25300000,0.57458777,0.43225991,0.36255808,0.31200000,0.36088987,0.23500000,0.67900000,0.52780663,0.84877634,0.60100000,0.52312114,0.88016779,0.54786992,0.44100000,0.71454795,0.40600000,0.63336988,0.48430697,0.62300000,0.85775039,0.49700000,0.86755325,0.28000000,0.41000000,0.29000000,0.49000000,0.47584950,0.54614545,0.38933141,0.42177569,0.44000000,0.38000000,0.30000000,0.35000000,0.43782491,0.59376254,0.40183930,0.47980812,0.64908555,0.70267977,0.51212255,0.36324971,0.37531746,0.40356716,0.47217357,0.63844986,0.30000000,0.24000000,0.33000000,0.53979562,0.41000000,0.20000000,0.35000000,0.62699337,0.54691447,0.93206856,0.46946850,0.65527331,0.53214520,0.87832701,0.41905965,0.63000000,0.38354612,0.56000000,0.35676991,0.29922638,0.26470026,0.18989366,0.73214090,0.74000000,0.79819873,0.74000000,0.68839278,0.75000000,0.68839278,0.68000000,0.30000000,0.12000000,0.45000000,0.06000000,0.32000000,0.44165042,0.49694187,0.63526724,0.53084984,0.45700000,0.28336175,0.24317002,0.28464587,0.16522301,0.41483438,0.62062299,0.24000000,0.32346029,0.15000000,0.62325274,0.24000000,0.41000000,0.23000000,0.32165450,0.30173569,0.03187675,-0.04782179,0.02956562,0.07973255,-0.22000000,-0.02696799,0.50000000,0.29494534,0.43000000,0.24679100,0.57558910,0.24645372,0.50000000,0.30096463,0.63082172,0.38295544,0.27817034,0.40538389,0.17616607,0.45000000,0.11803126,0.44000000,0.20000000,0.70900000,0.31000000,0.78000000,0.24900000,0.40600000,0.36000000,0.41900000,0.64812911,0.28077588,0.63883770,0.21744889,0.13203260,0.05807479,0.34675230,0.13066828,0.17070882,0.07549723,0.39777792,0.65397387,0.64048987,0.51913389,0.56000000,0.31000000,0.42000000,0.69214473,0.46503474,0.56777497,0.27300000,0.32500000,0.33400000,0.34400000,0.36447006,0.32547228,0.22000000,0.22000000,0.25000000,0.36074535,0.35000000,0.28000000,0.05000000,0.49300000,0.43500000,0.48750000,0.30000000,0.63750000,0.41000000,0.83236786,0.69647321,0.59323981,0.62000000,0.69000000,0.42600000,0.56100000,0.59600000,0.63761434,0.36827862,0.61000000,0.34526120,0.43000000,0.34074078,0.50395263,0.39705038,0.33000000,0.62919823,0.62000000,0.49965742,0.50000000,0.64770406,0.61000000,0.81511084,0.73821398,0.62482030,0.67288340,0.59189332,0.85976843,0.36461257,0.83993087,0.59600000,0.67200000,0.65700000,0.67500000,0.34870942,0.63444530,0.81000000,0.41428134,0.45614037,0.41797478,0.20000000,0.26000000,0.36000000,0.45000000,0E-8,0.01000000,0.20000000,0.23000000,0.38000000,0.47968275,0.72166665,0.50000000,0.12700000,0.38651119,0.68878395,0.71000000,0.42000000,0.70000000,0.39000000,0.44988642,0.42124197,0.34000000,0.11000000,0.42000000,0.37000000,0.74541280,0.61012712,0.50246344,0.57498891,0.45985678,0.54804849,0.58633763,0.36000000,0.55715993,0.63899544,0.72252703,0.75500000,0.78300000,0.80000000,0.51094514,0.51211435,0.30000000,0.29000000,-0.09000000,0.29200000,0.48527820,0.36800000,0.48100000,0.12555004,0.40900000,0.56200000,0.23400000,0.56300000,0.38000000,0.49100000,0.52327502,0.53200000,0.45552468,0.04390000,0.49628505,0.52600000,0.50675055,0.45000000,0.30000000,0.56000000,0.53000000,0.38000000,0.55000000,0.49400000,0.41300000,0.50100000,0.73800000,0.48615496,0.59296173,0.62349262,0.39200000,0.43689994,0.64200000,0.64601018,0.72488244,0.63960215,0.63960215,0.48739278,0.18000000,0.56000000,0.60000000,0.50500939,0.34000000,0.50000000,0.61000000,0.53033987,0.36425313,0.48600000,0.66400000,0.42800000,0.52248837,0.55429714,0.38759566,0.61466918,0.06676300,0.08029551,0.07456011,0.07456011,0.05173567,0.05000000,0E-8,0.09000000,0.76800000,0.45900000,0.84700000,0.65100000,0.79754237,0.58286220,0.31153461,0.21323135,0.51900000,0.38700000,0.75400000,0.60600000,0.73178375,0.63758279,0.62884328,0.61547860,0.63892541,0.14773733,0.34210000,0.23908753,-0.07010000,0.76740585,0.48100000,0.64600000,0.23908753,-0.07010000,0.76740585,0.48100000,0.64600000);
```

Comment: "Command lines entered at the console are limited to about 4095 bytes (not characters). " (https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html#R-commands_003b-case-sensitivity-etc). You may want to use a different method to read in your data, e.g. such as `read.csv` from a .csv file.

Comment: @jay.sf yeah, I'm running this in python and the data is auto-generated, I need to make something that works realtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

according to CRAN documentation:

"**Command lines entered at the console are limited4 to about 4095 bytes (not characters).**",

"**some of the consoles will not allow you to enter more, and amongst those which do some will silently discard the excess and some will use it as the start of the next line.**"

source: https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html#FOOT4

If you introduce some line breaks in command may solve the issue.